# Know if a cy instance has been destroyed

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there any way to know if an instance has been destroyed?

I wait for some network requests to return in order to update styling to my elements, but when some request finish I have already changed the cy instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance is destroyed `destroy` event is triggered.

```
cy.on('destroy', () => {console.log('destroyed')});
cy.destroy();
// console output: destroyed
```

There is also an undocumented method `cy.isDestroyed()` which returns `true/false`. Internally this method just returns `cy._private.destroyed` variable.

Comment: I was looking for a function, is a shame that is undocumented. I'll try to document it and see if it can be available in the docs.

Comment: A PR to document cy.destroyed was accepted. The undocumented method "isDestroyed" was renamed to "destroyed" and it looks like is going to appear in version 3.7.0. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/pull/2382